# Decode binary(16) from mysql into asci using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The output of mysql table is as

```
mysql> desc alienvault_siem.po_acid_event;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default          | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| ctx        | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| device_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| plugin_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| plugin_sid | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| ip_src     | varbinary(16)    | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| ip_dst     | varbinary(16)    | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| timestamp  | datetime         | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| src_host   | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI |                  |       |
| dst_host   | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI |                  |       |
| src_net    | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI |                  |       |
| dst_net    | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI |                  |       |
| cnt        | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm interested in `src_host`. In php, I have code as follows:-
.....

```
$sqlgraph       = "select count(distinct plugin_id, plugin_sid) as num_events,ip_src, hex(src_host) as name from alienvault_siem.po_acid_event AS acid_event WHERE 1=1 $query_where group by name having ip_src>0x00000000000000000000000000000000 order by num_events desc limit $limit";
        
        $rg = $conn->CacheExecute($sqlgraph);
    
                        
        if (!$rg)
        {
            print $conn->ErrorMsg();
        } 
        else 
        {
            while (!$rg->EOF) 
            {
        
                $data[]  = $rg->fields["num_events"];
                $label[] = $rg->fields["name"];

                $links[] = $forensic_link . '&ip_addr[0][0]=+&ip_addr[0][1]=ip_src&ip_addr[0][2]=%3D&ip_addr[0][3]=' . inet_ntop($rg->fields["name"]) . '&ip_addr[0][8]=+&ip_addr[0][9]=+&ip_addr_cnt=1';
              
                $rg->MoveNext();
            }
        }
        
        $colors = get_widget_colors(count($data));
        
        break;
```

The output on webpage looks like as I can see hex string of 32 length
[image]

In actual `src_host` contains for e.g

> alienvault
>
> Host-10-27-0-23

I want to know how to display it as asci strings instead of hex-decimal or binary. Thanks

Comment: show us some content of src_host

Comment: You can show the result of `SELECT HEX(ip_src)`. As a note, storing IP addresses as raw binary is extremely annoying. Just store them as their textual equivalent. You're not saving enough space here to make it worth the human expense of dealing with the binary data.